# .htaccess Redirect from Subdirectory to Root

Tags: wordpress, apache, .htaccess

We redesigned our site using Wordpress.  The original location of the old site was in a folder; www.domain.com/oldsite.  I'd like to redirect anyone landing in that folder to the root of the domain, where the new site is located. But, I need the redirect to strip off the filename from the end of the URL.

www.domain.com/oldsite/contact.php redirects to www.domain.com

I've tried the following, but it is non stripping the filename from the URL.

```
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^old-directory/(.*)$ https://www.domain.com/ [R=301,NC,L]
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: have you tried to follow this in order to use your wordpress from a subdirectory ? https://codex.wordpress.org/Giving_WordPress_Its_Own_Directory

Comment: Doesn't really apply.  Our original site was hosted at XYZHosting.com.  Our site on that host was in a folder: www.domain.com/folder/index.php.  When we moved to a new host, we redesiged the site using Wordpress, but we did so in the root.  We then changed our DNS and pointed to the new host.  But, when a visitor tries to find us using www.domain.com/folder/index.php, they are getting a 404.  We are looking for a way to point anyone landing in www.domain.com/folder to our new site at www.domain.com.